# Can't show the voted questions on view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My app is about an online pool, soo I have managed o make an add question/edit question/delete question, same thing to the answers..
I also made a vote system, so now i want to show the voted answers like the number of votes each answer have.( ".count()" i think). But I can not do it ...
 Here is my controller

```
     public async Task<ActionResult> Results(Vote vote,Answer answer)
    {
        using (var poolDbContext = new PoolContext())
        {

            if (poolDbContext.Votes.Count() == 0)
            {
                Vote Q = new Vote();

                Q.Questions = poolDbContext.Questions.ToList();

                poolDbContext.Votes.Add(Q);
                var count = poolDbContext.SaveChanges();
            }

            var Vote = poolDbContext.Votes.Include(A=>A.Questions).Single(A => A.AnswerId == answer.Id);
            var Answer = poolDbContext.Questions.Include(q => q.Answers).Single(q => q.Id == q.Id);
            var Question = await poolDbContext.Questions.Include(A => A.Answers).AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Id == r.Id);
            var CountVotes = poolDbContext.Votes.Count(q => q.Id == q.Id);
            var AllQuestions = Question.Text.ToList();
            var ShowResults = vote.AnswerId;
            answer.Text = Answer.Answers.ToString();
            answer.QuestionId=Answer.Id;
            return View(Answer);
        }
```

my view of that controller:

```
@model PoolManager.Models.Answer

 @{
     ViewData["Title"] = "Results";
 }

 <h2>Results</h2>

<div>
<h4>Vote</h4>
<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    @foreach (var q in Model.Votes)
    {
        @Model.Text
        <br />
        @Model.Votes.Count

    }
</dl>
 </div>
<div>
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">Edit</a> |
<a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
```

also here are my Models:

```
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public List<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
    public Answer()
    {
        Votes = new List<Vote>();
    }
}
public class Question
{
    public Question()
    {
        Answers = new List<Answer>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public Boolean Active { get; set; }
    public string SelectedAnswer { set; get; }
}
public class Vote
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string IpAdress { get; set; }
    public DateTime VoteDate { get; set; }
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { set; get; }
    public Vote()
    {
        Questions = new List<Question>();
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue you are facing with this code? What it is displaying? What you want it to display?

Comment: This code right now gives me an error sayng that poolDbCotext.Votes(Question) is empty.
I want to display something like this :
"Answer#1: 20 votes"

Comment: What does it display instead? Did you debug the code to see if right values are being populated in the model?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya All the values that I need are in "poolDbContext.Votes"

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya so can you help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@model PoolManager.Models.Question

{
ViewData["Title"] = "Results";
}

<h2>Results</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Vote</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        @Model.Text

        @foreach (var answer in Model.Answers)
        {
            <br />
            <label>
                @answer.Text:   @answer.Votes.Count();
            </label>
        }
    </dl>
</div>
```